# Why Japanese labels are not wrapping as English word in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, customlabel, translation

I am in trouble with Japanese labels in visualfore page while its lenth is too long than word is not wrapping in my pagesection

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!CONTAINS(sApiName, 'G2C_Item_SL_StartStudyingJapan__cN')}">
      <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.University_Degree}" />
      <apex:outputField value="{!oFormobject.C_Item_SL_StartStudyingJapan__c}" >
      </apex:outputField>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

[image]

Comment: It may be because there is no space is in japanese word, word is not wrap if no blank space is there between words. Please check this.

Comment: i have checked and found that there is already a white space in Japanese word

Comment: But, by the way i have inspected those column and found that property was
white-space: nowrap;

i have changed this property to white-space: normal;  and it worked for me.

thanks for your quick reply @Anurag Bhardwaj

Comment: @Gaurav: Pleased that you find a solution :)